# Retrieving client certificate from SSL session in mod_mono (in Apache 2.2.2 (Red Hat))

Tags: apache, ssl, mono, client-certificates, mod-mono

I am trying to set up a .NET web service in mod_mono that has historically has only run under IIS 6/7.

Most of it works well, except for one little detail: The web service is supposed to log the client certificate when the connections are made over HTTPS.

I have my Apache server running with mod_ssl and I can make successful connections to the service with a client certificate. I have verified my web service in IIS 7 and seen that it is able to pick up the client certificate if it is present.

It appears that `ClientCertificate.IsPresent` returns false always in mod_mono. Some googling reveals that this has been an issue in the past (where it only worked correctly under XPS).
I would like to believe that I have mis-configured something :-) Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Best regards,
Emil

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I needed to set `SSLOptions +ExportCertData` in httpd.conf and everything worked like a charm :-)